# Can't find table for web-scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape a table from https://2018.masters.com/en_US/scores/stats/fir.html
When I inspect the website itself, I can find the table code in the source code.  However when I print it using Beautiful Soup or open it with the chrome driver with Selenium, I can't seem to find the same table, or any table at all.

Comment: Tried with `https://2018.masters.com/en_US/scores/stats/index.html` and able to get the table with `//div[@class='stats_table']/table` xpath. Can you share you code and traceback.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data through the json response. Once you have that, you can just flatten out that json structure into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests

url = 'https://2018.masters.com/en_US/xml/gen/scores/fir.json'

response = requests.get(url).json()

table = response['round1']['player']
df = json_normalize(table)

df  = df.stats.apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(pd.Series).merge(df, left_index = True, right_index = True).drop(["stats"], axis = 1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
              round1            round2             round3            round4             total     id                  name
0   13 / 14 = 92.86%  10 / 14 = 71.43%    7 / 14 = 50.00%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  40 / 56 = 71.43%  32839      Hideki Matsuyama
1   13 / 14 = 92.86%  12 / 14 = 85.71%   11 / 14 = 78.57%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  48 / 56 = 85.71%   1666       Bernhard Langer
2   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%   11 / 14 = 78.57%   8 / 14 = 57.14%  41 / 56 = 73.21%  34360          Patrick Reed
3   12 / 14 = 85.71%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       18 / 28 = 64.29%  32366        Kevin Chappell
4   12 / 14 = 85.71%   8 / 14 = 57.14%   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  42 / 56 = 75.00%  29478          Kevin Kisner
5   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  14 / 14 = 100.00%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  46 / 56 = 82.14%  40098   Matthew Fitzpatrick
6   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%                                       22 / 28 = 78.57%   1823            Larry Mize
7   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%                                       22 / 28 = 78.57%  39113     Shubhankar Sharma
8   12 / 14 = 85.71%   7 / 14 = 50.00%    8 / 14 = 57.14%   8 / 14 = 57.14%  35 / 56 = 62.50%  28237          Rory McIlroy
9   11 / 14 = 78.57%   5 / 14 = 35.71%    7 / 14 = 50.00%   8 / 14 = 57.14%  31 / 56 = 55.36%  29725            Tony Finau
10  11 / 14 = 78.57%  12 / 14 = 85.71%   12 / 14 = 85.71%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  47 / 56 = 83.93%  25804          Bubba Watson
11  11 / 14 = 78.57%   8 / 14 = 57.14%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  40 / 56 = 71.43%  23108           Matt Kuchar
12  11 / 14 = 78.57%  10 / 14 = 71.43%                                       21 / 28 = 75.00%  21209         Sergio Garcia
13  11 / 14 = 78.57%   9 / 14 = 64.29%                                       20 / 28 = 71.43%  27556       Ted Potter, Jr.
14  11 / 14 = 78.57%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       19 / 28 = 67.86%   1887          Mark O'Meara
15  11 / 14 = 78.57%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       19 / 28 = 67.86%  20848         Angel Cabrera
16  11 / 14 = 78.57%  10 / 14 = 71.43%   11 / 14 = 78.57%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  24138           Ian Poulter
17  11 / 14 = 78.57%   9 / 14 = 64.29%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  39 / 56 = 69.64%  27644          Brian Harman
18  11 / 14 = 78.57%   7 / 14 = 50.00%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  38 / 56 = 67.86%  34046         Jordan Spieth
19  11 / 14 = 78.57%  12 / 14 = 85.71%   10 / 14 = 71.43%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  34098        Russell Henley
20  11 / 14 = 78.57%  10 / 14 = 71.43%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  26476           Chez Reavie
21  10 / 14 = 71.43%  12 / 14 = 85.71%   13 / 14 = 92.86%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  47 / 56 = 83.93%  26596            Ryan Moore
22  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%    7 / 14 = 50.00%   8 / 14 = 57.14%  34 / 56 = 60.71%  48081     Xander Schauffele
23  10 / 14 = 71.43%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       18 / 28 = 64.29%  45486   Joaquin Niemann (A)
24  10 / 14 = 71.43%  11 / 14 = 78.57%   11 / 14 = 78.57%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  47959     Bryson DeChambeau
25  10 / 14 = 71.43%  11 / 14 = 78.57%   10 / 14 = 71.43%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  40026         Daniel Berger
26  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%   11 / 14 = 78.57%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  21528        Henrik Stenson
27  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%                                       19 / 28 = 67.86%  23821       Yusaku Miyazato
28  10 / 14 = 71.43%  10 / 14 = 71.43%   10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  39 / 56 = 69.64%  24502            Adam Scott
29  10 / 14 = 71.43%  10 / 14 = 71.43%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  40 / 56 = 71.43%  32102         Rickie Fowler
30  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  38 / 56 = 67.86%  30110          Kyle Stanley
31  10 / 14 = 71.43%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       16 / 28 = 57.14%  25686          Jason Dufner
32  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%   11 / 14 = 78.57%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  40 / 56 = 71.43%  32816       Satoshi Kodaira
33  10 / 14 = 71.43%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       18 / 28 = 64.29%  46837         Yuxin Lin (A)
34  10 / 14 = 71.43%   5 / 14 = 35.71%   10 / 14 = 71.43%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  35 / 56 = 62.50%  24024          Zach Johnson
35  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  41 / 56 = 73.21%  22405           Justin Rose
36  10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%                                       19 / 28 = 67.86%  53165        Doc Redman (A)
37  10 / 14 = 71.43%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       16 / 28 = 57.14%  33293        Thomas Pieters
38  10 / 14 = 71.43%   7 / 14 = 50.00%                                       17 / 28 = 60.71%  48084          Wesley Bryan
39  10 / 14 = 71.43%   5 / 14 = 35.71%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  35 / 56 = 62.50%  34363        Tyrrell Hatton
40  10 / 14 = 71.43%  11 / 14 = 78.57%                                       21 / 28 = 75.00%   2300           Ian Woosnam
41   9 / 14 = 64.29%   8 / 14 = 57.14%   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  39 / 56 = 69.64%  12716       Charley Hoffman
42   9 / 14 = 64.29%   8 / 14 = 57.14%    8 / 14 = 57.14%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  34 / 56 = 60.71%  33448         Justin Thomas
43   9 / 14 = 64.29%   7 / 14 = 50.00%   11 / 14 = 78.57%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  36 / 56 = 64.29%  28089             Jason Day
44   9 / 14 = 64.29%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%  31323         Gary Woodland
45   9 / 14 = 64.29%   4 / 14 = 28.57%    6 / 14 = 42.86%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  28 / 56 = 50.00%  25364            Paul Casey
46   9 / 14 = 64.29%   9 / 14 = 64.29%                                       18 / 28 = 64.29%  54318     Matt Parziale (A)
47   9 / 14 = 64.29%   9 / 14 = 64.29%   10 / 14 = 71.43%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  39 / 56 = 69.64%  33399           Adam Hadwin
48   9 / 14 = 64.29%   4 / 14 = 28.57%                                       13 / 28 = 46.43%  46435           Austin Cook
49   9 / 14 = 64.29%  10 / 14 = 71.43%   11 / 14 = 78.57%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  43 / 56 = 76.79%  25198    Francesco Molinari
50   9 / 14 = 64.29%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%  27896           Ross Fisher
51   9 / 14 = 64.29%   6 / 14 = 42.86%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  33 / 56 = 58.93%  29454      Bernd Wiesberger
52   9 / 14 = 64.29%   5 / 14 = 35.71%   12 / 14 = 85.71%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  35296            Haotong Li
53   9 / 14 = 64.29%  10 / 14 = 71.43%   10 / 14 = 71.43%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  40 / 56 = 71.43%   1226          Fred Couples
54   9 / 14 = 64.29%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%  10423             Mike Weir
55   9 / 14 = 64.29%   9 / 14 = 64.29%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  39 / 56 = 69.64%  26499  Rafael Cabrera Bello
56   9 / 14 = 64.29%  13 / 14 = 92.86%    6 / 14 = 42.86%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  29221          Webb Simpson
57   8 / 14 = 57.14%  10 / 14 = 71.43%   10 / 14 = 71.43%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  30925        Dustin Johnson
58   8 / 14 = 57.14%  10 / 14 = 71.43%                                       18 / 28 = 64.29%  35450       Patrick Cantlay
59   8 / 14 = 57.14%   7 / 14 = 50.00%    8 / 14 = 57.14%   7 / 14 = 50.00%  30 / 56 = 53.57%  26851         Marc Leishman
60   8 / 14 = 57.14%  10 / 14 = 71.43%                                       18 / 28 = 64.29%  29420        Billy Horschel
61   8 / 14 = 57.14%  12 / 14 = 85.71%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  41 / 56 = 73.21%  46970              Jon Rahm
62   8 / 14 = 57.14%  10 / 14 = 71.43%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  52375         Doug Ghim (A)
63   8 / 14 = 57.14%  10 / 14 = 71.43%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  27408         Martin Kaymer
64   8 / 14 = 57.14%   7 / 14 = 50.00%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%   1717            Sandy Lyle
65   8 / 14 = 57.14%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       14 / 28 = 50.00%  26331      Charl Schwartzel
66   8 / 14 = 57.14%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       14 / 28 = 50.00%  26908            Yuta Ikeda
67   8 / 14 = 57.14%   5 / 14 = 35.71%    6 / 14 = 42.86%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  28 / 56 = 50.00%   1810        Phil Mickelson
68   8 / 14 = 57.14%   4 / 14 = 28.57%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  33 / 56 = 58.93%  25632          Jimmy Walker
69   8 / 14 = 57.14%   7 / 14 = 50.00%    4 / 14 = 28.57%  11 / 14 = 78.57%  30 / 56 = 53.57%   8793           Tiger Woods
70   7 / 14 = 50.00%   7 / 14 = 50.00%    9 / 14 = 64.29%   9 / 14 = 64.29%  32 / 56 = 57.14%   6567           Vijay Singh
71   7 / 14 = 50.00%   9 / 14 = 64.29%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  27064       Jhonattan Vegas
72   7 / 14 = 50.00%   6 / 14 = 42.86%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  35 / 56 = 62.50%  37455            Si Woo Kim
73   7 / 14 = 50.00%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%  29970       Dylan Frittelli
74   7 / 14 = 50.00%   6 / 14 = 42.86%                                       13 / 28 = 46.43%  24361             Pat Perez
75   7 / 14 = 50.00%   7 / 14 = 50.00%                                       14 / 28 = 50.00%  32139         Danny Willett
76   7 / 14 = 50.00%   9 / 14 = 64.29%   12 / 14 = 85.71%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  38 / 56 = 67.86%  30911       Tommy Fleetwood
77   7 / 14 = 50.00%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%  32757        Patton Kizzire
78   6 / 14 = 42.86%   9 / 14 = 64.29%                                       15 / 28 = 53.57%   6373   Jose Maria Olazabal
79   6 / 14 = 42.86%   4 / 14 = 28.57%                                       10 / 28 = 35.71%  22378       Trevor Immelman
80   6 / 14 = 42.86%   8 / 14 = 57.14%    9 / 14 = 64.29%  10 / 14 = 71.43%  33 / 56 = 58.93%  29974         Branden Grace
81   6 / 14 = 42.86%   8 / 14 = 57.14%                                       14 / 28 = 50.00%  27349            Alex Noren
82   6 / 14 = 42.86%   7 / 14 = 50.00%  14 / 14 = 100.00%   8 / 14 = 57.14%  35 / 56 = 62.50%  26329      Louis Oosthuizen
83   6 / 14 = 42.86%   7 / 14 = 50.00%    7 / 14 = 50.00%  13 / 14 = 92.86%  33 / 56 = 58.93%  35891         Cameron Smith
84   6 / 14 = 42.86%  11 / 14 = 78.57%    8 / 14 = 57.14%  12 / 14 = 85.71%  37 / 56 = 66.07%  30978  Kiradech Aphibarnrat
85   5 / 14 = 35.71%  11 / 14 = 78.57%                                       16 / 28 = 57.14%  29518        Brendan Steele
86   3 / 14 = 21.43%   5 / 14 = 35.71%                                        8 / 28 = 28.57%  52569       Harry Ellis (A)
```